# Is it possible to build OpenSSL 1.0.0g using VC6 on windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, openssl, visual-c++-6

I tried to build Open SSL 1.0.0g on windows using VC6 and Nmake  I got in6_addr undefined error .

This is a structure which is available in higher versions of VC++ (ex VC++8)

But my application is in VC6 so I couldn't use OpenSSL libraries (ssleay.lib , libeay.lib ) build using VC++8 with VC6 application as I'm getting linker errors as given below

```
ssleay32.lib(ssl_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __time32
libeay32.lib(mem_dbg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __localtime32
libeay32.lib(o_time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __gmtime32
ssleay32.lib(d1_lib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __ftime32
libeay32.lib(by_dir.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stat32
```

is there any workaround to solve this? , please some one help me to solve this issue.

This is my error when I tried to build openSSL 1.0.0g using VC6

```
.\apps\s_cb.c(731) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'in6_addr'
        .\apps\s_cb.c(731) : see declaration of 'in6_addr'
.\apps\s_cb.c(764) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'in6_addr'
        .\apps\s_cb.c(764) : see declaration of 'in6_addr'
.\apps\s_cb.c(812) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'in6_addr'
        .\apps\s_cb.c(812) : see declaration of 'in6_addr'
.\apps\s_cb.c(845) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'in6_addr'
        .\apps\s_cb.c(845) : see declaration of 'in6_addr'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x2'
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to compile openssl 1.0.0g using VC6 compiler but it requires Windows SDK 2003 to make this compilation succeed  as the mentioned files and APIs come with Windows SDK 2003 and above.